# Django request impossibly slow, can't find why

Tags: django, performance, cpu-usage

I have an Apache2 + mod_python setup which has begun responding *impossibly* slow since some days - two seconds of processor time for any request of my app.
Some interesting points:

- Debugbar says it's ~15ms of query time. DB is not the main suspect
- Logging with datetime.now() shows 0.1s is spent inside the view, and 40ms more are spent inside a requestcontext
- I could not find an easy way to time template rendering.

Any idea of where can I look?

Comment: Have your tried to run strace on the Apache process to see what it is doing? Though this will primarily help you, if the problem is I/O, not if it is CPU usage in the user-space.

Comment: Does it happen immediately after an Apache restart? We had similar problems that would happen on a long-running Apache, but kicking it got us a snappy app again. So we kicked it every night with a cron job.

Comment: @ChrisM a quick look at `top` output live shows that one request generates a two-second 100% CPU spike for ~ two seconds, so user space CPU time is the first candidate.

Comment: @Spacedman sadly, it happens the same right after a restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose it had an infinite loop. How would you find it?

I imagine you would just pause it in the debugger and look at the code at the various levels of the stack, because you know the loop is somewhere on the stack. Right?

Suppose the loop *isn't* infinite, merely taking a long time. Is that much different?

No matter what the problem is, if it is costing you some percent of time, like 90%, or 50%, or 20%, that's the probability you will catch it in the act when you pause it. So if you pause it several times, you're going to see it. The worse it is, the fewer times you have to pause it and look. It will be obvious.

So forget about timing. [Just find out what it's doing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)

---

In response to question, here is some mod_python doc:

> 5.4.1 PythonEnablePdb Syntax:
>   PythonEnablePdb {On, Off}
>   Default: PythonEnablePdb Off
>   Context: server
>   config, virtual host, directory,
>   htaccess Override: not None Module:
>   mod python.c When On, mod python will
>   execute the handler functions within
>   the Python debugger pdb using the
>   pdb.runcall() function. Because pdb is
>   an interactive tool, start httpd from
>   the command line with the -DONE
>   PROCESS option when using this
>   directive. As soon as your handler
>   code is entered, you will see a Pdb
>   prompt allowing you to step through
>   the code and examine variables.
>
> 5.4.2 PythonDebug Syntax:
>   PythonDebug {On, Off} Default: PythonDebug Off
>   Context: server config, virtual host,
>   directory, htaccess Override: not None
>   Module: mod python.c Normally, the
>   traceback output resulting from
>   uncaught Python errors is sent to the
>   error log. With PythonDebug On
>   directive specified, the output will
>   be sent to the client (as well as the
>   log), except when the error is IOError
>   while writing, in which case it will
>   go to the error log. This directive is
>   very useful during the development
>   process. It is recommended that you do
>   not use it production environment as
>   it may reveal to the client
>   unintended, possibly sensitive
>   security information.

Comment: If I had infinite (or too long) loops I'd take the time before and after, and log it. How would you suggest I pause the execution?

Comment: @Agos: I quoted some doc in the answer. You can run the Python debugger PDB interactively, and you can get a stack trace when you interrupt it. That's the basis of the technique. Don't think of it as logging time before / after. Think of it as "It's slowing way down. I wonder what it's doing."

Answer (score 0):

Profiling the app is a good start point (https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ProfilingDjango).

Before looking into the profile statistics, make sure you know what's the request/response cycle of django (or whatever framework you are using).

Most of the cases, things got messed up in the view, for other cases, it might be in middleware layers. Watch for which layer you are profiling, functional wise or everything involved in the request/response.

Other tricks like compare performance between dev/prod mode might be useful too. Try use django development server to make sure apache/mod_python is not the culprit.